# get custom post type by tag

Tags: wp-query, loop

Is it possible to retrieve post entry for a custom post type by tag, I have been trying with the following code, however it just locks me into a infinte loop.

```
<aside class="supporting_images">
    <?php /*<?php if($post->ID == 241) : echo apply_filters('the_content', '[slideshow=3]'); endif;  ?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>*/?>

    <?php if($post->ID == 241) : ?>
        <?php
            $query = new WP_Query();
            $query->query('tag=branding');
        ?>
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
            hello
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to setup the post for the query by changing the following line to get rid of the infinite loop.

`<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>`

If your looking for a custom post type, you'll need to specify that in the query arguments:

`<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( "post-type" => "yourposttype", "tag" => "branding" ) ); ?>`

You can see most (if not all) of the query parameters in the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Use `tag_slug__in` not `tag` ([#REF](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters))

**Example :**

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'post_type' => 'your-posttype', // or 'any'
   'tag_slug__in' => 'your-tag',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
));
```

**Step :** Filter by Post-type **then** filter by Tag

*Another answers "Filter by Post-type **and** filter by Tag"*

Answer (score 0):

To avoid infinite loop, you need to loop over resulting posts:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(
    array( "post_type" => "yourposttype", // not "post-type" !
           "tag" => "branding"
    ) );
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    Hello
<?php endwhile; ?>
```