# Why am I getting an infinite loop with have_posts?

Tags: post-meta, loop, recursive

I have the following code, which causes an infinite loop for some reason. Can anybody explain what's going on please?

Thanks!

```
<?php 

$flagged_stores = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'store', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'meta_key' => 'flagged', 'limit' => 10 ) );

   if($flagged_stores->have_posts()): ?> 
        <div class="table">
            <table class="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Store</th>
                    <th>Flag Reason</th>
                    <th>Delete Flag</th>
                </tr>
                <?php while($flagged_stores->have_posts()): ?>
                    <td><?php echo the_title(); ?></td>
                    <td><?php// echo get_post_custom_values('flagged'); ?></td>
                    <td><?php// echo "Delete"; ?></td>
                <?php endwhile;?>
            </table>
    <?php else: ?>
            No flags found.
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this answer: [get custom post type by tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27909/get-custom-post-type-by-tag/33154#33154)

I believe you'd use `$flagged_stores->the_post()` inside `while` loop.

Comment: +1 - well spotted; it should indeed read: `<?php while($flagged_stores->have_posts()): $flagged_stores->the_post(); ?>` - @yuval: did the endless loop always show the same title?

Comment: @Michael yes, because you don't seek post by post without [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post)

Comment: Also don't do `echo the_title()` it's just `the_title()`, as it prints itself by default. Usually you use `echo` with functions starting with get_, like in `echo get_the_title()`

Answer (score 1):

try and use `'posts_per_page'` instead of `'limit'` - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Comment: Still no luck. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what caused the infinite loop, but your WP_Query is off.

```
$flagged_stores = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'store', 'orderby' => 'ID', 'meta_key' => 'flagged', 'posts_per_page' => 10 ) );
```

I updated `'orderby'` and `'posts_per_page'`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Michael in a comment to brownian, use `while` and don't forget `$your_query->the_post();` that [iterates the post index](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post/). Wrap `while` in `if($your_query->have_posts())` to have an option for no entries.

```
<?php
if($flagged_stores->have_posts()):
 while($flagged_stores->have_posts()):
  $flagged_stores->the_post(); 
  ?> 
    <!-- your html -->
  <?php 
 endwhile;
else: 
 ?>
 No flags found.
 <?php 
endif; 
?>
```